# Hyperledger composer generator: Trying to copy from a source that doesn't exist (no concepts support for Angular)

Tags: hyperledger-composer, yo

I have a `composer-rest-server` running on `localhost:3000`. To go with that, I tried to generate an Angular 2 app using `yo hyperledger-composer`. My business network models also have a `abstract concept Spray{...}` present.

I believe the documentation is outdated as I was presented with slightly different options than on the documentation. After choosing Angular and following through the steps, I got an 
`AssertionError: Trying to copy from source that does not exist ... /concept/concept.component.ts`

Based on some quick google searches, I was able to find this issue on their Github - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3927 however in my case, I am not even able to build the Angular app so I don't even get to the compilation stage.

Is there any way to build the app right now where it's at?

Comment: hi there - that's odd - although (per that issue) you can't create an asset (via form) if it contains a concept, presently - you should be able to generate the app. Suggest to `rm -rf` the old directory - then follow this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial#step-six-generating-an-application to generate (you could leave your REST server running (I assume the REST APIs have been working fine with your REST server at this point in time)

Comment: Regenerated my BNA and tore down and restarted Fabric. I'm back at the angular app generation step now by following your link. Using `yo hyperledger-composer:angular` and following the steps eventually leads me to `Error: Composer runtime (0.19.13) is not compatible with client (0.19.14-20180809130819)`

Comment: Nevermind, I updated my modules and got past that error but I'm back at AssertionError now. I'll make a Github issue after trying to reproduce it fresh.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error on a new machine. Posting a github issue at `generator-hyperledger-composer`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Github issue explaining steps to reproduce this and also included a hacky fix which is to comment out the lines in the generator code which copy over the `concept` files.

Link - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4328